# Collation change accent sensitive column

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, collation, squirrel-sql

Is there any way to make search query accent sensitive in one column of my table?

the column's and table's collation are in LATIN1_GENERAL_CS and I don't want to change the table.

How to change the values of my column that they are already with accent: Example replace "Systèmes" with Systemes ?

`ALTER TABLE NameTable MODIFY COLUMN NameColumn varchar(40) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course you can...

1. modify one column of your table
2. use the COLLATE operator in the query to retrieve data with a CI/CS or AI/AS (or much more)

   ALTER TABLE <table_name>
   ALTER COLUMN <columns_name> <data_type> COLLATE collation_name

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   <table_name>
WHERE  <columns_name> COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = 'Système'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the last SQL Query but I dont have the collation with accent insensitive : Error: Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CI_AI' .

Comment: try to use one of the collations returned by the following query: SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()